# How can I load dynamic content with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, load

I'm following "[How to Load In and Animate Content with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/)" and everything works fine, but if I have other links in the loaded `<div/>` the script doesn't work. Can anyone spot the bug in the following code?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('.nav li a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

    $('.nav li a').click(function(){

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }
        return false;

    });

});
```

My scenario

- start from site index
- click 'contact'
- contact 'content div' is loaded
- in contact content div I have other link 'map.html' I want open it that same at other, only 'content div' loading --> and it don't work - site is loading normal

Comment: try running action you're running after **document is ready** after your ajax request completed.

Comment: `site index --> i click 'contact' --> contact 'content div' loaded --> in contact content div i have other link e.g 'map.html' I want open it that same at other, only 'content div' loading --> and it don't work - site is loading normal` huh?!

Answer (score 0):

If the link in the content you are talking about is the `.nav li a` link, then the problem here is that the `.click` event is only assigned once (on documentready) and does not affect content loaded *after* documentready.

So the easiest way would be changing `$('.nav li a').click(function(){` to

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function(){
```

With this the event handler will be attached to content loaded later as well.

---

**Note:** Depending on your jQuery version you may have to use a different method for this **[.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** behaviour:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```